# If the app uses serveral thread, will it run smoothly than using one UI Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

My Application is using Single Thread( UI Thread ) right now,
and it has some code like...

1. keep checking my phone state
2. google map service
3. keep adding marker to current state
4. and there's a "popupmenu"

   and when the "Popupmenu" inflates, app frame drops.

I've never tried splitting a Single Thread to two, is this the right way to prevent the janky(laggy) frame?

Or is there something like alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

No, more threads are probably not the answer here.

First of all the android gui *is* single threaded, you are only allowed to interact with it using the main thread.

Are you doing something similar to the official doc/guide here for popup menu?

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus#PopupEvents

Meaning code something lik this:

```
public void showMenu(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);

    // This activity implements OnMenuItemClickListener
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
    popup.inflate(R.menu.actions);
    popup.show();
}
```

If you are not doing much more than this you can't optimize this much more, not easily.
If you are, perhaps you can simplify it to the basic example from the docs.

I would otherwise assume that you are consuming too much of the frames' time budget doing other things that hopefully can be optimized/paused instead so the popup menu inflating is  not going over your limits.